# how to get full relative path of the image in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to emit an image from client and server.
It is easy to load the image at the server side where the nodejs code is running that is from the local machine. so can this be modified by means of obtaining relative path? if so, how the coding have to be done using javascript or jquery.

```
<script>
var url = 'http://localhost:5151';
var socket = io.connect(url);
function image()
{

alert($('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0].name);

url=$('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0].name;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the snippet.
when I upload the image from local server it uploads the image. The same when it is doen with the client machine with the mentioned url above. It won't view the whole path of the image. So that it doesn't upload it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the `src` of an `<img/>`?

Comment: yeah. im not using img tag. im using input file tag to open the image. when it is in the local server it opens. But when the client open it from other machine it can't open the image

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you're using so i can help?

Comment: yeah I have included some snippet